# How to get data async from socket and display it on page?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

There is variable:

```
public message: any;
```

Then in template I tried to show message if it is not empty:

```
<div *ngIf="message">Message</div>
```

But message is showen only when I do click in area where is div placed.

Full code is:

```
ngOnInit() {
    connection.on("receivePassportData", data => {
       console.log(data);
       this.message = data;
    });
}
```

I get data in `console.log(data);` but message is not rendered in template.

Comment: You assing an obj to a string propertry

Comment: Sorry, updated, it is object, not string

Comment: I dont know why Angular is not rendering this varaiable

Comment: I can share full code

Comment: Are you using rxjs ?

Comment: See my update question with full code

Comment: I get data from socket in ` ngOnInit`

Comment: what is the `changeDetection` strategy of the component?

Comment: Where you have written the function to connects to the server using the io.connect() call ?

Comment: It is default strategy: `@Component({
  selector: "app-visitor-component",
  templateUrl: "./visitor.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./visitor.component.css"],
  providers: [ConfirmDialogsSimpleService]
})`

Comment: I have connection to socket in ngOnInit() also I have tried to move it in constructor, result is the same

Comment: https://blog.codewithdan.com/pushing-real-time-data-to-an-angular-service-using-web-sockets/

Comment: I use SignalR, so you offer push icome data to Subject? then subscribe in subject?>

Comment: Why you are not using observable? you just subscribe in ngOnInit and unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210058/discussion-between-opv-and-santosh-shinde).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  explicitly run this code in a zone using NgZone

```
 constructor(private zone: NgZone)  {}

 public connect(options: any) {
   // custom code
   [...]

  // socket event
  this.socket.on('receivePassportData', (data) => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.message = data;
    });     
  });
 }
```

For more help please check [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5046).

Also, I would like to suggest you create an

1. Angular Service that Subscribes to the Data Stream Provided by the Server.
2. Create an Angular Service that Subscribes to the Data Stream Provided by the Server.
3. Emit data received in the Angular Service (from the service) to Observable subscribers
4. Then Subscribe to the Service Observable in a Component ngOnInit method.

For more help please check [here](https://blog.codewithdan.com/pushing-real-time-data-to-an-angular-service-using-web-sockets/).

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngIf="message && Object.keys(message).length > 0">Message</div>
```

Try this.